# Lebesgue Measure of "excursions" of Brownian Motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I know that the set $S$ where a standard Brownian motion $M:=B[\mathbb{R}]$ attains a strict local minimum is a.s. dense in $\mathbb{R}$. For every point $s \in S$, consider the interval $(s,t)$ such that $B(y) > B(s)$ for all $y \in (s,t)$, and such that $B(t) = B(s)$ (it exists because $M$ is a.s. diverging to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$). Call the set of such intervals $I$.

My question is, is it true that the complement of the union of all the intervals in $I$ is a.s. of Lebesgue measure $0$?

Somehow, it seems to be difficult as, with probability $1$, this complement will not contain any interval.

I'd be very happy if someone could give me a vague hint or a reference.

Comment: If $t>s$, then with probability one there exist $x,y\in(s,t)$ such that $B(x)<B(s)<B(y)$. So I think your initial assumption is incorrect.

Comment: I had looked up something, here: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~peres/bmall.pdf At page 20 it says something about local extrema of BM. My assumption in the beginning is that there exists a set of paths $P$ such that, for every $p \in P$, I can find a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of strict local minima for $p$, and $P$ has Wiener measure 1. What you say is like: fix any point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for almost every path $x$ is not a local minimum. I am not sure these are the same, but I am new to the subject so I might easily be missing something...

Comment: @Jason I forgot the tag.